# Inserir um checkbox dentro de um botão JavaScript JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma lista com um `mousedown` dentro de cada `<li></li>` e eu preciso colocar um `checkbox` dentro desse `li` tbm só que o `checkbox` não pode ter o `mousedown`.

Há algum jeito de fazer isso?

```html
<li class="list-group-item" onmousedown="modalCartao(1)">
  <input style="float: right;" type="checkbox" id="checkbox">  
</li>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso, precisa tratar o evento *mousedown* no input e cancelar o evento usando [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
$("li").mousedown(function() {
  // faz log de uma mensagem para demonstrar
  console.log( "li.mousedown()" );
});

$("li > input").mousedown(function(event) {
 // aqui cancela o evento. Se comentar essa linha vai ver que aparece o log do event do parent
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
li {
  border: solid 1px #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <li class="list-group-item">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">  
   </li> 
 </ul>
```

Comment: E como seria para passar um parametro dentro do li mousedown? Porque eu ali no modalCartao(1), esse 1 é um exemplo de um id que eu puxo pra abrir minha modal daquele reigstro

Comment: Eu também queria saber um pouco sobre esse li > input. É possível voce me explicar de forma resumida como que funciona isso?

Comment: sim, esse seletor seleciona "dentro de todos elementos **LI** todos os INPUT **>** aninhados abaixo dele", ou seja, seleciona os elementos `<li><input>`. Se seus inputs tiverem uma classe, pode selecionar direto por ela

Comment: E outra pergunta como que passo parametro para ->$("li").mousedown(function() { }

Comment: pode passar o evento, ou o proprio objeto com `this` `$("li").mousedown(function(evento)`, mas pode fazer como no seu exemplo, com `onmousedown="modalCartao(1)"

Comment: Ah deu certo, muito obrigado mesmo, uma ultima pergunta, porque (li > input)  nao cancela o evento do checkbox (de selecionar o checkbox) e apenas cancela o da <li>?